# What is a difference between python3-mock and unittest.mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, package, pytest

In Ubuntu you can install package python3-mock. mock library has been added to Python 3.3 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0417/).
What is a difference between these libraries? Which one is recommended to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unittest.mock` is recommended if you are using python 3.3 or newer.

I think `python3-mock` is the same as the version on pypi:
https://pypi.org/project/mock/#description

> mock is now part of the Python standard library, available as unittest.mock in Python 3.3 onwards.
>
> This package contains a rolling backport of the standard library mock code compatible with Python 2.6 and up, and 3.3 and up.

So it's actually a backport for old Python.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which python version you are using in your project.

For Python versions < 3.3 you should install mock lib.

For others else, including 3.3, you don't need because it were incorporated to [standard lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).